# Type converting slices of interfaces

Tags: go, go-reflect, go-interface

I'm curious why Go does't implicitly convert `[]T` to `[]interface{}` when it will implicitly convert `T` to `interface{}`.  Is there something non-trivial about this conversion that I'm missing?

Example:

```
func foo([]interface{}) { /* do something */ }

func main() {
    var a []string = []string{"hello", "world"}
    foo(a)
}
```

`go build` complains

> cannot use a (type []string) as type []interface {} in function argument

And if I try to do it explicitly, same thing: `b := []interface{}(a)` complains

> cannot convert a (type []string) to type []interface {}

So every time I need to do this conversion (which seems to come up a lot), I've been doing something like this:

```
b = make([]interface{}, len(a), len(a))
for i := range a {
    b[i] = a[i]
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, or standard library functions to help with these conversions?  It seems kind of silly to write 4 extra lines of code every time I want to call a function that can take a list of e.g. ints or strings.

Comment: so you define "implicitly convert []T to []interface{}" to mean "allocating a new slice and copying all the elements over". That is inconsistent with what "implicitly convert T to interface{}" does, which is just a view of the same value as a more generic static type; nothing is copied; and if you type-assert it back to type T, you would still get the same thing back.

Comment: wasn't thinking in too much detail about how it would be implemented, just that at a higher level it would be convenient to be able to easily convert a whole list to another type as a workaround for not having generic types.

Comment: Many years later there's hope: Go Generics are on their way, and there' already a playground where you can see and try them in action https://go2goplay.golang.org/ (Background: https://go.dev/blog/generics-next-step)

Answer (score 334, accepted):

In Go, there is a general rule that **syntax should not hide complex/costly operations**.

Converting a `string` to an `interface{}` is done in O(1) time. Converting a `[]string` to an `interface{}` is also done in O(1) time since a slice is still one value. However, converting a `[]string` to an `[]interface{}` is O(n) time because each element of the slice must be converted to an `interface{}`.

The one exception to this rule is converting strings. When converting a `string` to and from a `[]byte` or a `[]rune`, Go does O(n) work even though conversions are "syntax".

There is no standard library function that will do this conversion for you. Your best option though is just to use the lines of code you gave in your question:

```
b := make([]interface{}, len(a))
for i := range a {
    b[i] = a[i]
}
```

Otherwise, you could make one with `reflect`, but it would be slower than the three line option. Example with reflection:

```
func InterfaceSlice(slice interface{}) []interface{} {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    if s.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        panic("InterfaceSlice() given a non-slice type")
    }

    // Keep the distinction between nil and empty slice input
    if s.IsNil() {
        return nil
    }

    ret := make([]interface{}, s.Len())

    for i:=0; i<s.Len(); i++ {
        ret[i] = s.Index(i).Interface()
    }

    return ret
}
```

Comment: it might be slower, but it would work generically with any type of slice

Comment: This whole answer applies to `map`s too btw.

Comment: This also applies to `channels` as well.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation, if possible can you add ref. for `Converting a []string to an interface{} is also done in O(1) time`?

Comment: Added a benchmark for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69309292/. You're right - its 33% faster to use a loop.

Comment: "syntax should not hide complex/costly operations." - And this is why I like Python, not Go...

Comment: Converting each element to `interface{}` is not just `O(N)` *time*, but more significantly, requires `N` allocations.

Answer (score 80):

The thing you are missing is that `T` and `interface{}` which holds a value of `T` have different representations in memory so can't be trivially converted.

A variable of type `T` is just its value in memory. There is no associated type information (in Go every variable has a single type known at compile time not at run time). It is represented in memory like this:

- value

An `interface{}` holding a variable of type `T` is represented in memory like this

- pointer to type `T`
- value

So coming back to your original question: why go does't implicitly convert `[]T` to `[]interface{}`?

Converting `[]T` to `[]interface{}` would involve creating a new slice of `interface {}` values which is a non-trivial operation since the in-memory layout is completely different.

Comment: This is informative and well written (+1), but you're not addressing the other part of his question: "Is there a better way to do this..." (-1).

Comment: According to the [Golang wiki article "InterfaceSlice"](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice), the data layout in the interface is slightly different: `Each interface{} takes up two words (one word for the type of what is contained, the other word for either the contained data or a pointer to it)`.

Answer (score 22):

Here is the official explanation: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice

```
var dataSlice []int = foo()
var interfaceSlice []interface{} = make([]interface{}, len(dataSlice))
for i, d := range dataSlice {
    interfaceSlice[i] = d
}
```

Comment: Good info but it's not an official explanation. It's a wiki where everyone can edit.

Comment: How should I convert `[]interface` to the type I expect such as `[]map[string]interface{}` ?

Answer (score 19):

In Go 1.18 or later, use the following function to convert an arbitrary slice type to `[]interface{}` or its alias `any`:

```
func ToSliceOfAny[T any](s []T) []any {
    result := make([]any, len(s))
    for i, v := range s {
        result[i] = v
    }
    return result
}
```

The Go 1.18 generics feature does not eliminate the need to convert an arbitrary slice to `[]any`.  Here's an example of where the conversion is required:  The application wants to [query a database](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Query) using the elements of a `[]string` as the variadic query arguments declared as `args ...any`. The function in this answer allows the application to query the database in a convenient one-liner:

```
rows, err := db.Query(qs, ToSliceOfAny(stringArgs)...)
```

Answer (score 10):

Try `interface{}` instead. To cast back as slice, try

```
func foo(bar interface{}) {
    s := bar.([]string)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This begs for the next question: how the OP is then supposed to iterate over `bar` so as to interpret it as "a slice of any type"? Note that his three-liner creates a `[]interface{}`, not `[]string` or a slice of other concrete type.

Comment: -1: This only works if bar is []string, in which case, you may as well write: `func foo(bar []string) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: use a type switch, or use reflection as in the accepted answer.

Comment: OP is going to have to figure out his type at run time any way. Using non slice `interface{}` will make the compiler not complain when passing an argument as in `foo(a)`. He could either use reflect or type switching (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch) inside `foo`.

Answer (score 5):

In case you need more shorting your code, you can creating new type for helper

```golang
type Strings []string

func (ss Strings) ToInterfaceSlice() []interface{} {
    iface := make([]interface{}, len(ss))
    for i := range ss {
        iface[i] = ss[i]
    }
    return iface
}
```

then

```golang
a := []strings{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
sliceIFace := Strings(a).ToInterfaceSlice()
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason []T (a slice of a specific type) cannot be directly converted to []interface{} is because the memory layout of the underlying array is not compatible with storing elements of different types.

When you have a slice []T, the memory layout of the underlying array is designed to store elements of type T. Each element in the array occupies a specific amount of memory based on its type T.

If you were allowed to convert []T to []interface{}, it would mean that the memory layout of the underlying array should be able to accommodate elements of any type, including interface{}. However, the original underlying array was designed to store elements of type T, not interface{} or any other type.

The issue is that the memory layout of the underlying array cannot simultaneously satisfy the requirements of different types. For example, if the original slice was []string, the memory layout of the underlying array is optimized for storing strings.

If you were able to convert []string to []interface{}, and then try to store elements of a different type (e.g., int) in the same underlying array, it would lead to an invalid memory layout. The memory allocated for strings would not be appropriate for storing int values, and accessing those values as interface{} could result in unexpected behavior or crashes.

To preserve type safety and maintain the integrity of the memory layout, Go requires you to manually create a new slice of []interface{} and copy the elements from the original slice, performing the necessary conversions. This ensures that the memory layout of the new slice is appropriate for interface{} values and avoids conflicting memory layouts or type mismatches.

So, in summary, the conversion from []T to []interface{} is not allowed because the memory layout of the underlying array is specific to the element type T, and it cannot be reconfigured to accommodate elements of different types without causing memory layout conflicts or type mismatches.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious how much slower it is convert interface arrays via reflection vs. doing it inside a loop, as described in [Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12754757/901019). Here's a benchmark comparison of the two approaches:

```
benchmark                             iter      time/iter   bytes alloc         allocs
---------                             ----      ---------   -----------         ------
BenchmarkLoopConversion-12         2285820   522.30 ns/op      400 B/op   11 allocs/op
BenchmarkReflectionConversion-12   1780002   669.00 ns/op      584 B/op   13 allocs/op
```

So using a loop is **~20% faster** than doing it via reflection.

Here's my test code in case you'd like to verify if I did things correctly:

```golang
    import (
        "math/rand"
        "reflect"
        "testing"
        "time"
    )
    
    func InterfaceSlice(slice interface{}) []interface{} {
        s := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
        if s.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
            panic("InterfaceSlice() given a non-slice type")
        }
    
        // Keep the distinction between nil and empty slice input
        if s.IsNil() {
            return nil
        }
    
        ret := make([]interface{}, s.Len())
    
        for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
            ret[i] = s.Index(i).Interface()
        }
    
        return ret
    }
    
    type TestStruct struct {
        name string
        age  int
    }
    
    var letters = []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    
    func randSeq(n int) string {
        b := make([]rune, n)
        for i := range b {
            b[i] = letters[rand.Intn(len(letters))]
        }
        return string(b)
    }
    
    func randTestStruct(lenArray int, lenMap int) map[int][]TestStruct {
        randomStructMap := make(map[int][]TestStruct, lenMap)
        for i := 0; i < lenMap; i++ {
            var testStructs = make([]TestStruct, 0)
            for k := 0; k < lenArray; k++ {
                rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
                randomString := randSeq(10)
                randomInt := rand.Intn(100)
                testStructs = append(testStructs, TestStruct{name: randomString, age: randomInt})
            }
            randomStructMap[i] = testStructs
        }
        return randomStructMap
    }
    
    func BenchmarkLoopConversion(b *testing.B) {
        var testStructMap = randTestStruct(10, 100)
        b.ResetTimer()
    
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            obj := make([]interface{}, len(testStructMap[i%100]))
            for k := range testStructMap[i%100] {
                obj[k] = testStructMap[i%100][k]
            }
        }
    }
    
    func BenchmarkReflectionConversion(b *testing.B) {
        var testStructMap = randTestStruct(10, 100)
        b.ResetTimer()
    
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            obj := make([]interface{}, len(testStructMap[i%100]))
            obj = InterfaceSlice(testStructMap[i%100])
            _ = obj
        }
    }
```

Comment: The language provides all the facilities to write reproducible benchmarks, profile the code, to effectively understand what is going on under the hood. See also `prettybench` or `benchcmp`

Comment: @mh-cbon ok, benchmark updated with `-bench`.

Answer (score 1):

Though you can use a generic function to convert a slice to a slice of `interface{}`, it may be most appropriate and cheapest in terms of execution time to change `foo` to a generic function if possible.

For example:

```golang
func foo[T any](slice []T) { /* do something */ }

func main() {
    var a []string = []string{"hello", "world"}
    foo(a)
}
```

Now there is no conversion necessary at all.

Answer (score -3):

Convert `interface{}` into any type.

Syntax:

```
result := interface.(datatype)
```

Example:

```
var employee interface{} = []string{"Jhon", "Arya"}
result := employee.([]string)   //result type is []string.
```

Comment: Are you sure about it? I don't think this is valid. You're going to see it: 

`invalid type assertion: potato.([]string) (non-interface type []interface {} on left)`