# trying to use interface{} to a slice to select random element

Tags: go

I've been trying to implement a function which can randomly select an element from any type of slice (like python's random.choice function)

```
func RandomChoice(a []interface{}, r *rand.Rand) interface{} {
    i := r.Int()%len(a)
    return a[i]
}
```

However, when I try to pass in a slice of type []float32 into the first argument this error occurs:

`cannot use my_array (type []float32) as type []interface {} in function argument`

is this a fundemental misuse of interface{}? is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Re: *is there some better way to do this?*

IMO there is. The OP approach is inefficient wrt to simple:

```
var v []T
...

// Select a random element of 'v'
e := v[r.Intn(len(v))]   
...
```

Note that both of the approaches will panic for `len(v) == 0` until a pre-check for this is made.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although I'm not entirely sure I understand the lingo. Are you suggesting that it would be better not to use a function like RandomChoice at all?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. No type conversions/assertions, statically type checked and better run time performance for writing about a dozen characters in-line. Which is perhaps even less typing than `e := RandomChoice(a, r).(T)` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Using reflection:

```
func RandomChoice(slice interface{}, r *rand.Rand) interface{} {
    x := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    return x.Index(r.Intn(x.Len())).Interface()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Properties_of_types_and_values):

> Two types are either identical or different.
>
> Two named types are identical if their type names originate in the
> same TypeSpec. A named and an unnamed type are always different. Two
> unnamed types are identical if the corresponding type literals are
> identical, that is, if they have the same literal structure and
> corresponding components have identical types. In detail:
>
> - Two array types are identical if they have identical element types and
>   the same array length.
> - Two slice types are identical if they have
>   identical element types.
> - Two struct types are identical if they have the same sequence of fields, and if corresponding fields have the same names, and identical
>   types, and identical tags. Two anonymous fields are considered to have
>   the same name. Lower-case field names from different packages are
>   always different.
> - Two pointer types are identical if they have identical base types.
> - Two function types are identical if they have the same number of parameters and result values, corresponding parameter and result types
>   are identical, and either both functions are variadic or neither is.
>   Parameter and result names are not required to match.
> - Two interface types are identical if they have the same set of methods with the same names and identical function types. Lower-case
>   method names from different packages are always different. The order
>   of the methods is irrelevant.
> - Two map types are identical if they have identical key and value types.
> - Two channel types are identical if they have identical value types and the same direction.

And:

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to
> T") in any of these cases:
>
> - x's type is identical to T.
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a named type.
> - T is an interface type and x implements T.
> - x is a bidirectional channel value, T is a channel type, x's type V and T have identical element types, and at least one of V or T is not
>   a named type.
> - x is the predeclared identifier nil and T is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T.
>
> Any value may be assigned to the blank identifier.

The combination of these two results that you can't assign a []MyType to an []interface{}.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer to part of my question. I also like the quote from Stephen on the link from my answer: "In Go, there is a general rule that syntax should not hide complex/costly operations."

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can hardly believe after all the searching, that the first listed related question was: [Type converting slices of interfaces in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753805/type-converting-slices-of-interfaces-in-go?rq=1) which pretty much contains the answer.
Changing RandomChoice to use the InterfaceSlice function described in the answer to that question yields:

```
func RandomChoice(slice interface{}, r *rand.Rand) interface{} {
    islice := InterfaceSlice(slice)
    i := r.Int()%len(islice)
    return islice[i] 
}
```

although apparently this answer is not very well performing, because it requires the entire slice to be converted to []interface{}...