# How to use passed struct in function

Tags: go

I saw somewhere, but I do not remember where, that a slice struct is passing through function like the following code snippet.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func passSlice(arg interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(arg)
}

func main() {

    res := []struct {
        Name string
    }{}

    passSlice(res)

}
```

I have no idea, how to use here a slice struct in the function. Have someone a idea, how can I use it in the function?

Comment: Good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12754757/6309

Comment: Why don't you work yourself through the Go tour and Effective Go, both available on golang.org?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type converting slices of interfaces in go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753805/type-converting-slices-of-interfaces-in-go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the slice struct (or any other value stored in an *interface*), you must first do a **[type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)** or **[type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements)**:

**Type assertion:**

```
func passSlice(arg interface{}) {
    // Put args value in v if it is of type []struct{ Name string }
    v, ok := arg.([]struct{ Name string })
    if !ok {
        // did not contain a value of type []struct{Name string}
        return
    }
    for _, s := range v {
        fmt.Println(s.Name)
    }
}
```

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/KiFeVC3VQ_

*Type switches* are similar, but can have cases for multiple types.

There is also an option of using the `reflect` package, allowing you to more dynamically handle interface values without knowing before hand what types you can expect, but using reflection is also more complex. To know more about using reflection in Golang, you can look here:

- [Laws of reflection](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)
- [reflect package](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)

Comment: Remembering too that you can "one-line" that assertion to `v, ok := arg.([]struct{ Name string }); !ok { return }`.. with the braces in the right spots (couldn't do it in comments).