# Using map[string]int as parameter of type map[interface{}]interface{}

Tags: go

I have a function:

```
func ReturnTuples(map_ map[interface{}]interface{}) [][]interface{} {
```

In which I'm trying to call like this:

```
m := make(map[string]int)
m["k1"] = 7
m["k2"] = 13
fmt.Println(ReturnTuples(m))
```

But I'm getting

```
cannot use m (type map[string]int) as type map[interface {}]interface {} in argument to ReturnTuples
```

Shouldn't it work since `string` and `int` both implement `interface{}`?

I've searched and the best I could find was [Convert map[interface {}]interface {} to map[string]string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975880/convert-mapinterface-interface-to-mapstringstring) but it won't answer why I cannot use `m` as an argument.

I also believe that if the argument of the function were only `interface{}` it would work too, since `map[something][something]` implements `interface`, right? What is the best way to do it, and why it won't work in my case?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#covariant_types

Comment: @Volker but I don't see the method type being wrong, I didn't even enforce the method type since I'm just printing the function's return value. The problem, as says the compiler, is on the argument type

Comment: The reason why you cannot pass `map[string]int` as that `map[interface{}]interaface{}` is that `string`, `int`, and `interface{}` all has different data structure. `string` is a single pointer which is maybe 64bit, `int` is maybe signed 64bit value, however `interface{}` is structure of two pointers named [emptyInterface](https://golang.org/src/reflect/value.go#L174)

Comment: And the reason why you **can** pass `string` and `int` to `interface{}` is that golang's runtime is implicitly converting it using [runtime.convT2E()](https://golang.org/src/runtime/iface.go#L191) when needed.

Comment: So that means that if you want to convert `map[string]int` to `map[interface{}]interface{}`, you have to call `runtime.convT2E` to all the keys an values, of cause you can do it if you write your code to do that, but golang's runtime just don't do it automatically.

Comment: @ymonad thanks, I understood. So I should use map_ interface{} as an argument?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs It depends on what you are trying to do in `ReturnTuples()`, maybe you can use reflection, or sometime define your interface instead, or there's another clever way to do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A solution to your problem, simply initiate the map as an empty interface of empty interfaces:

`m := map[interface{}]interface{}`

then you can assign any type key or value you want in the 'ReturnTuples' function.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/pmWOzRe73L)

NOTE: remember that if you want to use the values later as the original types, you will need to use type assertion because now they are of type `interface{}`

You may do something this like this, were `anything` is one map value which you can get using a for loop:

```
switch v := anything.(type) {
      case string:
            fmt.Println(v)
      case int32, int64:
            fmt.Println(v)
      case string:
            fmt.Println(v)
      case SomeCustomType:
            fmt.Println(v)
      default:
            fmt.Println("unknown")
}
```

If you are looking for an explanation for the "why"
[@ymonad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2427222/ymonad) gave a full answer so I wont repeat it again.

hope it make sense

PS: don't get the down votes on the question, a legit one in my eyes...

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. And yes, I'm tired of these downvotes. Everything is downvoted now...

Comment: Looks like the playground link no longer works due to "Unavailable For Legal Reasons".

Answer (score 1):

You can type assert in the function itself.

```
func test(m interface{},key interface{}) bool { // Map is passed as reference
        ma := m.(map[interface{}]interface{})
        if _, ok := ma[key]; ok == false {
        ....
}
```