# How to pass variable parameters to Sprintf in golang

Tags: go, slice

I'm lazy, want to pass many variables to `Printf` function, is it possible?
(The sample code is simplified as 3 parameters, I require more than 10 parameters).

I got the following message:

> cannot use v (type []string) as type []interface {} in argument to fmt.Printf

```
s := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}  // Result from regexp.FindStringSubmatch()
fmt.Printf("%5s %4s %3s\n", s[1], s[2], s[3])  

v := s[1:]
fmt.Printf("%5s %4s %3s\n", v...)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, just declare your slice to be of type `[]interface{}` because that's what [`Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) expects. `Printf()` signature:

```
func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

So this will work:

```
s := []interface{}{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
fmt.Printf("%5s %4s %3s\n", s[1], s[2], s[3])

v := s[1:]
fmt.Printf("%5s %4s %3s\n", v...)
```

Output ([Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/4emcCimGTR)):

```
b    c   d
b    c   d
```

`[]interface{}` and `[]string` are not convertible. See this question+answers for more details:

**[Type converting slices of interfaces in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753805/type-converting-slices-of-interfaces-in-go)**

If you already have a `[]string` or you use a function which returns a `[]string`, you have to manually convert it to `[]interface{}`, like this:

```
ss := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
is := make([]interface{}, len(ss))
for i, v := range ss {
    is[i] = v
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to convert to interface from result of  regexp.FindStringSubmatch()

Comment: @DanielYCLin You have to do that manually. See my edited answer.