# How to create an array of struct arrays of different types?

Tags: struct, go, slice

In my program I got 2 models:

```
type User struct {
    Name string
}

type Article struct {
    Title string
}
```

And I got arrays of data of these structs:

```
users := []User
articles := []Article
```

I'm trying to iterate over both of them at the same piece of code:

```
models := [][]interface{} {users, articles}
for _, model := range models {
    log.Printf("%#v", model)
}
```

But I'm receiving an error:

```
cannot use users (type []User) as type []interface {} in array element
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This cannot be done. Go is statically typed. Redesign your solution.

Comment: You can't convert any slice to `[]interface{}`. For explanation and solution see [Type converting slices of interfaces in go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753805/type-converting-slices-of-interfaces-in-go).

Comment: @Volker, icza Thank you, guys.

Comment: @WhiteAngel the "go way" is using interfaces, I posted a solution that might help :)

Answer (score 4):

You should use `[]interface{}` instead of `[][]interface{}`
Try it on the <kbd>[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JNCeCIa0R7)</kbd>

If you want to iterate all structs in your inner arrays, you need to cast them to the proper type and then iterate, like this:

```
for _, model := range models {
    if u, ok := model.([]User); ok {
        for _, innerUser := range u {
            log.Printf("%#v", innerUser)
        }
    }
    if a, ok := model.([]Article); ok {
        for _, innerArticle := range a {
            log.Printf("%#v", innerArticle)
        }
    }
}
```

Try it on the <kbd>[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vTTFQbatKV)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this is what I was trying to avoid - `switch` statement and checking types. In this case I would have repeating blocks that will do absolutely the same things for each type. So, Go doesn't allow you to do this in a clean way? For me the problem is that I might have 10 different models and even more.

Comment: Maybe you can use interfaces for that?

Comment: @RoninDev like in my answer?

Comment: @PabloFernandez exactly

Answer (score 1):

How about using interfaces to solve your problem? you can even use the default `fmt.Stringer` interface, used by `fmt.Prtinf` and other standard methods.

Example:

```
package main

import "log"
import "fmt"

type User struct {
    Name string
}

type Article struct {
    Title string
}

func (art Article) String() string {
    return art.Title
}

func (user User) String() string {
    return user.Name
}

func main() {
    models := []interface{}{User{"user1"}, User{"user2"}, Article{"article1"}, Article{"article2"}}
    for _, model := range models {
        printable := model.(fmt.Stringer)
        log.Printf("%s\n", printable)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/W3qakrMfOd

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not getting your requirements, but what's wrong with just

```
models := []interface{} {users, articles}
for _, model := range models {
    log.Printf("%#v\n", model)
}
```