# Coercing map types in Go

Tags: go, casting

Is type coercion of maps possible in Go? What I'd like to do is something like:

```
type IDMap map[string]bool
type ObjectMap map[string]Object
```

and then write functions which take arguments of type `map[string]interface{}` so that I can handle either of these base types as an argument, like this:

```
func (im IDMap) Intersect(other map[string]interface{}) {
    result = make(IDMap, 0)
    for k := range im {
        if _, ok := other[k]; ok {
            result[k] = true
        }
    }
    return result
}

func (om ObjectMap) Intersect(other map[string]interface{}) {
    result = make(ObjectMap, 0)
    for k := range om {
        if _, ok := other[k]; ok {
            result[k] = om[k]
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

allowing me to call the Intersect method of either type with an object of either type. When I try, I get a type error message. Is something like this possible?

Comment: No. Types in Go are invariant. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753805/type-converting-slices-of-interfaces-in-go

Answer (score 0):

Try using `interface{}` and `switch` type checking:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type IDMap map[string]bool
type ObjectMap map[string]interface{}
type Map interface {
    Intersect(interface{}) Map
}

func main() {
    im1 := IDMap{"a": true, "b": false, "c": true, "e": false}
    other1 := IDMap{"b": true, "d": false, "e": true}
    other2 := ObjectMap{"b": false, "x": 1, "y": 3.4, "z": "hello"}
    other3 := map[string]interface{}{"m": 5.4, "n": false, "o": "world", "b": "foo", "a": "bar"}

    overlap1 := im1.Intersect(other1)
    check(overlap1)

    overlap2 := im1.Intersect(other2)
    check(overlap2)

    overlap3 := im1.Intersect(other3)
    check(overlap3)


    im2 := ObjectMap{"a": "hello", "b": 4.5, "c": 10, "e": []string{"what?"}}
    other4 := IDMap{"b": true, "d": false, "e": true}
    other5 := ObjectMap{"b": false, "x": 1, "y": 3.4, "z": "hello"}
    other6 := map[string]interface{}{"m": 5.4, "n": false, "o": "world", "b": "foo", "a": "bar"}

    overlap4 := im2.Intersect(other4)
    check(overlap4)

    overlap5 := im2.Intersect(other5)
    check(overlap5)

    overlap6 := im2.Intersect(other6)
    check(overlap6)

}

func check(m Map) {
    fmt.Println(m)
}

func (im IDMap) Intersect(other interface{}) Map {
    result := IDMap{}

    switch o := other.(type) {
    case IDMap:
        for k := range im {
            if _, ok := o[k]; ok {
                result[k] = true
            }
        }
    case ObjectMap:
        for k := range im {
            if _, ok := o[k]; ok {
                result[k] = true
            }
        }
    case map[string]interface{}:
        for k := range im {
            if _, ok := o[k]; ok {
                result[k] = true
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}

func (om ObjectMap) Intersect(other interface{}) Map {
    result := ObjectMap{}

    switch o := other.(type) {
    case IDMap:
        for k := range om {
            if _, ok := o[k]; ok {
                result[k] = om[k]
            }
        }
    case ObjectMap:
        for k := range om {
            if _, ok := o[k]; ok {
                result[k] = om[k]
            }
        }
    case map[string]interface{}:
        for k := range om {
            if _, ok := o[k]; ok {
                result[k] = om[k]
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```