# Passing []*io.PipeWriter to io.MultiWriter

Tags: go

I have a bunch of `*io.PipeWriter` created and would like to make a multiwriter based on all those pipewriters in a function. So I call a function something like

```
func copyToWriters(reader *bufio.Reader, errs chan error, writers []*io.PipeWriter) {
  for _, writer := range writers {
    defer writer.Close()
  }
  mw := io.MultiWriter(writers)
  _, err := io.Copy(mw, reader)
  if err != nil {
    errs <- err
  }
}
```

I call the method with arguments `copyToWriters(reader, errs, []*io.PipeWriter{w1, w2})`

But it says 
`cannot use writers (type []*io.PipeWriter) as type []io.Writer in argument to io.MultiWriter`. But
if I change `io.MultiWriter(writers)` to `io.MultiWriter(writers[0],writers[1])` it works. How can I make the existing function work by not having to pass writers separately.

Comment: @Volker can you give the reason ? since `*io.PipeWriter` implements the `Writer` interface, it seems to be legitimate to use `*io.PipeWriter` instead of `io.PipeWriter`: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#PipeWriter

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: A, sorry, you are correct, PipeWriter is not an interface. Forget it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Golang's type system does not allow casting `[]*io.PipeWriter` to `[]io.Writer` even when `*io.PipeWriter` implements `io.Writer` since it requires O(n) operation [(reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753805/type-converting-slices-of-interfaces-in-go/12754757#12754757).

The best you can do is create another `[]io.Writer` and copy the pipe writers into it

```
ws := make([]io.Writer, len(writers))
for i, w := range writers {
    ws[i] = w
}
mw := io.MultiWriter(ws...)
```

And reason why you nead `...`, read [the document](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)