# os.FileInfo mock not matching

Tags: unit-testing, go, interface, mocking, typing

in one of my golang Projects i went to mock the `os.FileInfo` for testcases.

I am not sure if I understand the interface handling of golang correctly.
As far as I know the following piece of code should work, but I get an Compilererror saying that the interface does not match.

I modified [this](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#example_ReadDir) go-doc example a bit in case you want to test it out yourself.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type file interface{
    Name() string
} 

func readFiles() []file{
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return files
}

func main() {
    files := readFiles()

    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file.Name())
    }
}
```

Following at the golang doc, the `ioutil.ReadDir(".")` should Return a slice of `os.FileInfo` which should be a specialisation of my selfwritten `file` interface.

Can anyone help me out of this hell of misconceptions and entanglements, please?

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: That's what https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface talks about. The problem is the slice and not the interface.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/12754757/859353

Answer (score 0):

`os.FileInfo` is interface and it can converted to `file`. But you try to convert `[]os.FileInfo` to `[]file`. Slice is not interface, and can not be asserted.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the other answer and comments, os.FileInfo does fulfill the `file` interface you've defined, but a slice of os.FileInfo does not implicitly convert to a slice of your `file` interface. A simple fix would be to have your `readFiles` do the conversion explicitly, e.g.

```
func readFiles() []file{
    fileInfos, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    files := make([]file, len(fileInfos))
    for i, fi := range fileInfos {
        files[i] = fi
    }

    return files
}
```