# How should I declare an interface that has a method to return a slice of a different interface?

Tags: go

Here is an example that I created where I declare my first struct which is a `Toolbox` that contains a slice `Hammers`. I made an interface for `Toolbox` and `Hammer` so that others can use my functions without having to use my structs as long as they follow my interface implementation.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ToolboxInterface interface {
    GetHammers() []HammerInterface
}

type HammerInterface interface {

}

type Toolbox struct {
    Hammers []Hammer
}

func (t Toolbox)GetHammers() []HammerInterface  {
    return []HammerInterface{t.Hammers}
}

type Hammer struct {
    Color string
}

func CountHammersInToolbox(t ToolboxInterface) int {
    hammers := t.GetHammers()
    return len(hammers)
}

func main()  {
    toolbox := Toolbox{Hammers: []Hammer{
        {Color: "Red"},
        {Color: "Blue"},
        {Color: "Green"}}}

    fmt.Println(len(toolbox.Hammers))

    fmt.Println(CountHammersInToolbox(toolbox))
}
```

My `ToolboxInterface` declares the `GetHammers()` method which I have implemented. However the CountHammersInToolbox method returns 1 instead of 3 as seen in the output.

```
uberswe$ go run scratch/main.go 
3
1
```

I have tried different variations of this but I feel a bit stuck. I don't understand why it is returning 1 but I suspect that I am declaring my interface method in the wrong way.

**How should I declare an interface that has a method to return a slice of a different interface?**

Comment: I think I solved it by changing my `Toolbox` struct to `Hammers []HammerInterface` but I am not sure why this should be declared this way. I am interested in answers that can explain this well or link to good guides/documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your interface definitions. The problem is that you're not properly converting `[]Hammer` to `[]HammerInterface`.  It looks like you expect this to happen magically, but it doesn't.

In this bit of code:

```
func (t Toolbox) GetHammers() []HammerInterface  {
    return []HammerInterface{t.Hammers}
}
```

You're probably expecting that the returned result is a slice of 3 `HammerInterface`s, but instead, you're getting a single `HammerInterface`, which is actually a slice of three `Hammers`s.

You must do this conversion manually. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12753805/13860) for more details.

```
func (t Toolbox) GetHammers() []HammerInterface  {
    hammerInterfaces := make([]HammerInterface, len(t.Hammers))
    for i, hammer := range t.Hammers {
        hammerInterfaces[i] = t.Hammers[i]
    }
    return hammerInterfaces
}
```

In most real-world scenarios, your error would be caught by the compiler, because your slice of hammers (`t.Hammers`) would not satisfy the `HammerInterface` interface, but in your case, since that interface is empty, it matches *any type*, as `interface{}` would.