# Cannot use type X as type Y even if same interface

Tags: go, types, interface

I am trying to write a function which takes anything that implements a certain interface as an argument.

I have defined an interface `KeyProvider` which specifies a `GetKey()` method. I have defined a function that uses this interface `ToKeys()`.

```golang
type KeyProvider interface {
    GetKey() *datastore.Key 
}

func ToKeys(l []*KeyProvider) []*datastore.Key {
    keys := make([]*datastore.Key, len(l))
    for i, vp := range l {
        v := *vp
        keys[i] = v.GetKey()
    }
    return keys
}
```

I have implemented this interface on a struct `User`.

```golang
type User struct {
    Key *datastore.Key
}

func (u *User) GetKey() *datastore.Key {
    return u.Key
}
```

I try to use the `ToKeys()` method.

```golang
func foo(users []*User) {
    keys := ToKeys(users)
}
```

But I get this error:

```
cannot use users (type []*User) as type []*KeyProvider in argument to ToKeys
```

Why? And how can I get something like this working?

Comment: `*User` implements `KeyProvider`, it does not implement `*KeyProvider`. But even so `[]*User` is not directly convertible to `[]KeyProvider`. You need to loop over the users slice and create a new key provider slice from its individual elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12754757/965900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always keep in mind, Go requires explicit type conversions.

1.`func ToKeys(l []*KeyProvider) []*datastore.Key` should be `func ToKeys(l []KeyProvider) []*datastore.Key`.
should almost never use pointer to an interface, use interface.

2.not allow to convert `[]*User` to `[]KeyProvider` directly, because of different representation in memory (if you are interesting about [slice's internal](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)).

you need to convert the slice manually, for example:

```
func foo(t []*User) {
    s := make([]KeyProvider, len(t))
    for i, v := range t {
        s[i] = v
    }

    keys := ToKeys(s)
}
```

check this two urls:
https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_with_same_underlying_type