# How do I avoid repeating similar function N times

Tags: go

I have N functions that return slices of different types.

All of the returned types has a method: `func (t *T)GetName() string`

I have no control to these functions.

Now I try to combine the N functions to 1:

I created an interface which has only 1 method `GetName()`, but I get error

```
package main

import (
    //"fmt"
)


type A struct{
}
func (a *A) GetName() string {
return "A"
}

type B struct{
}

func (b *B) GetName() string {
return "B"
}

type Alphabet interface{
  GetName() string
}

func main() {
}
func returnA() Alphabet{
a := &A{} 
return a
}

func returnAs()[]Alphabet{
return []*A{&A{},&A{},&A{}}
}
```

Here `returnA` works fine but returnAs gives compile error:

`prog.go:46:12: cannot use []*A literal (type []*A) as type []Alphabet in return argument`

https://play.golang.org/p/ZWUhIg31GE5

**Update:**

Sorry I did not explain my case clearly,

I have N functions that return slices of different types.

I now use N wrapper functions to return values from original functions.

What I currently have:

```
func returnAs()[]*A{
    as := giveMeAs() // giveMeAs() returns []*A 
    return as
}

func returnBs()[]*B{
    bs := giveMeBs() // giveMeBs() returns []*B 
    return bs
}
```

What I want:

```
func returnAlphabet(s string)[]Alphabet {
   switch s{
   case "A":
   return giveMeAs()
   case "B":
   return giveMeBs()
   //...
   }
}
```

I'm not good at design patterns, I just feel written this way might be easier for the caller(myself)

Comment: Go does not allow *directly* converting a slice of one type to a slice of another, besides reflection there's nothing you can do but to loop over one to construct the other. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12754757/965900

Comment: If this is the use case, then `giveMeAs`, `giveMeBs`, etc should probably return `[]Alphabet`.

Answer (score 4):

Your function returns a slice of interfaces, so that's what you need to construct. What you want is.

```
func returnAs() []Alphabet {
    return []Alphabet{&A{},&A{},&A{}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func returnAs() (as []Alphabet) {
    for _, a := range []*A{&A{},&A{},&A{}} {
        as = append(as, a)
    }
    return 
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/s3Y4ccZIeYr

Comment: This should work, but I have to repeat this for all of my cases