# Append to the slice of base interface slice of the implementations

Tags: go, interface, append, slice

Why the below doesn't work?

```
locations := make([]*LocationEvent, 0)
data := make([]Event, 0)
data = append(data, locations...)
```

where `*LocationEvent` (struct) implements `Event` (interface).

While the below works fine:

```
data = append(data, &LocationEvent{}, &LocationEvent{})
```

So how it is different when expanding the actual `[]*LocationEvent` slice using `...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slice type must match the type of the variadic arguments in the `append` function exactly. `locations` is of type `[]*LocationEvent`, and thus not compatible with `[]Event`. There is no automatic "downcasting" in Go when working with slices.

You have to copy the locations to a new slice of `Event`, or add the items of `locations` one-by-one to the `data` slice.

For more explanation look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12754757/6655315