# omit type of array in a function argument with golang

Tags: go, type-inference

I'm writing a write method, to write an array of value to InfluxDB

What I would like is to be able to have something like:

```
func (influxClient *InfluxClient) Write(myArray []interface{}) (error) {
    fmt.Print(myArray)
    // Insert into DB
    return nil

}
```

Where `myArray` could be an array with any objects inside

I tried to use `myArray []interface{}` to ommit myArray's type, but it doesn't work, I get:

```
Cannot use 'meters' (type []models.Meter) as type []interface{}
```

Is it possible to achieve it ?

How should I do ?

Comment: if you try to formating a slice of something to a slice of interface, you should maybe have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753805/type-converting-slices-of-interfaces-in-go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `[]models.Meter` and `[]interface{}` are two different types for the Go compiler.

Using `interface{}` is not a best-practice typically. It would be better to define your own type and use that instead.

Having said that, the quickest solution for your case should be to make `Write` function a variadic one. Like the example below.

https://play.golang.org/p/KzzFMAjQvRa

```
func Write(myArray ...interface{}) (error) {
    fmt.Printf("Slice: %v\n", myArray)
    // Insert into DB
    return nil

}
```

Comment: Yes, thing is I would have a single array of "objects", so ... it might not be the best fit

Comment: Are you saying that the slice of objects is already built before calling `Write` method? In that case you just need to invoke it like this: `Write(mySlice...)`.

Comment: Yep, my input in a slice of objects. Objects type may vary. I will check if that works

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you copy first to an []interface instance

```
func main() {

   // Copy from your explicit type array
   var interfaceSlice []interface{} = make([]interface{}, len(models.Meter))

   for i, Modelvalue := range models.Meter {
       interfaceSlice[i] = Modelvalue
   }    

   influxClient.Write(interfaceSlice)
}
```

[Wiki Interface slice and arrays](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice)

[Playground sample](https://play.golang.org/p/SujzWh7d56g)