# Converting interfaces with json decoding

Tags: json, go, pointers, interface, slice

Consider the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)


func testNoPointer() interface{} {
    return []int{}
}

func testPointer() interface{} {
    return &[]int{}
}


func main() {
    jsonString := "[1]"
    
    noPointer := testNoPointer()
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", noPointer)
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &noPointer)
    if (err == nil) {
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", noPointer)
    }

    pointer := testPointer()
    err2 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &pointer)
    if (err2 == nil) {
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", pointer)
    }   
}
```

It outputs:

```
[]int
[]interface {}
*[]int
```

Why does unmarshaling erase the type information for values? As a consequence this `decoded := noPointer.([]int)` will throw `interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not []int`. Is it possible to cast it to the correct type?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're asking. Does this help, though? https://stackoverflow.com/q/12753805/13860

Comment: I am asking why unmarshaling changes the type of the value from []int to []interface {}. While this is not a problem if pointers are used.

Comment: 1. "Why does unmarshaling erase the type information for values?" It doesn't. You cannot erase type information in Go. Go is statically typed. 2. Using Printf  to debug the type requires a _real_ good  understanding of a) how typing works in Go and b) what Printf does. Don't do that. It is going  to confuse you more that it will help. 3. Your  problem stems from using a pointer to a interface. 4. This looks like a XY-Problem.

Comment: Can you explain what's happening then after unmarshaling? Specifically why noPointer.([]int) fails @Volker
Thanks

Comment: "Specifically why noPointer.([]int)" It fails because the dynamic value of noPointer is []interface{}`. The more interesting  question would be _why_ the dynamic  type of noPointer is []interface{} but that is just what json.Unmarshal does when unmarshaling  a JSON array. See icza's answer for details. Protip: Never (really) use a pointer to an interface value (unless you really know what you are  doing and why you really want that). Just don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `testNoPointer()` and `testPointer()` functions return `interface{}` values. Understand that once you put (wrap) something in an interface value, you can no longer modify that.

So in the first case you have an interface value wrapping a slice. You can't add elements to the wrapped slice, because that requires modifying the slice header (e.g. its length field), so unmarshaling in the first case cannot use the value you pass for unmarshaling. It has to create a new value. And since you're unmarshaling into an `interface{}` value (type of `noPointer` is `interface{}`), the `encoding/json` package is free to choose whatever type it sees fit for unmarshaling, and [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) documents that:

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> ```
> bool, for JSON booleans
> float64, for JSON numbers
> string, for JSON strings
> []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> nil for JSON null
> ```

You're unmarshaling a JSON array, so it chooses `[]interface{}`.

In your second example you are wrapping `*int[]` in an interface value. It is again true that you cannot modify the value wrapped in the interface, but this doesn't have to happen. The `encoding/json` package can just modify the *pointed* value, so the wrapped pointer in the interface can remain unchanged, so the `encoding/json` package can use the pointer, and hence can retain the element type.

Note that in the second example it's important that the wrapped pointer is not `nil`, because if it would be `nil`, the `encoding/json` package could not use the interface value wrapping the pointer: a `nil` pointer points to nowhere, so a new, pointer would have to be allocated. But then again we're at a point where `encoding/json` unmarshals into an `interface{}` value (type of `pointer` is `interface{}`), so the `encoding/json` package would revert to creating an `[]interface{}` for the JSON array being unmarshaled.

You can test this when a `testPointer2()` returns a `nil` pointer wrapped:

```
func testPointer2() interface{} {
    var x *[]int
    return x // this will be a nil pointer
}
```

And testing it:

```
pointer2 := testPointer2()
err3 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &pointer2)
if err3 == nil {
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", pointer2)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T3zjU7rp249)):

```
[]interface {}
```

We again "lost" the type information, because the interface value wrapping a `nil` pointer could not be used.

See relevant issue / discussion on github: [encoding/json: clarify what happens when unmarshaling into a non-empty interface{} #26946](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26946)