# How to insert array of struct into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to insert data that is stored in an array of struct into a MongoDB using the `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` library. My struct is

```
type Statement struct {
    ProductID        string `bson:"product_id" json:"product_id"`
    ModelNum         string `bson:"model_num" json:"model_num"`
    Title            string `bson:"title" json:"title"`
}
```

and my insertion code is

```
func insert(stmts []Statement) {
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

    quickstartDatabase := client.Database("quickstart")
    testCollection := quickstartDatabase.Collection("test")
    testCollection.InsertMany(ctx, stmts) // This is giving error
}
```

The compiler gives the error `cannot use stmts (variable of type []Statement) as []interface{} value in argument to testCollection.InsertMany` at the `InsertMany` command.

I have tried marshalling the struct before inserting using `bson.Marshal` but even that doesn't work. How do I insert this data into the DB?

Comment: Have you tried creating a list of interface{} and cast your Statement? Something like:

interfaceStmts := []interface{}{}
for _, s := range stmts{
    interfaceStmts = append(interfaceStmts, s)
}

Comment: @Mihai Yes, that worked. Thank you. But doesn't iterate over every element in the array? Which is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: It does iterate over the elements in the array unfortunately. There is no nice and easy way to do the conversion. I think the good news is that the big O complexity of the code will not change with this extra iteration since the lib will also iterate over the batch so complexity is still O(n). This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753805/type-converting-slices-of-interfaces/12754757#12754757 should cover the reason behind the language design.

Answer (score 5):

insertMany accept `[]interface{}`

i would make like this

```golang
newValue := make([]interface{}, len(statements))

for i := range statements {
  newValue[i] = statements[i]
}

col.InsertMany(ctx, newValue)
```

Comment: Note: if you make using len(statements), then the first len(statements) records will be nil in newValue