# Golang: Genric struct implement does not match generic interface

Tags: go

I am experimenting with go generics, and I have encountered this issue. Why is `Schedule` not matching `any`?

##### Code

```golang
func demo(m Model[any]) Model[any] {
    return m
}

type Model[M any] interface {
    FindOne(db *gorm.DB, conds ...any) (m M)
}

type DbOperations[M any] struct{}

func (d DbOperations[M]) FindOne(db *gorm.DB, conds ...any) (m M) {
    res := db.First(&m, conds)
    if res.Error != nil {
        return m
    }
    return m
}


// the program does not compile because of this function
func a() {
    m := DbOperations[Schedule]{}
    get(m) // <= error occurs here
}
```

##### Error message

```
../models/operations.go:103:6: cannot use m (variable of type DbOperations[Schedule]) as type Model[any] in argument to get:
    DbOperations[Schedule] does not implement Model[any] (wrong type for FindOne method)
        have FindOne(db *gorm.DB, conds ...any) (m Schedule)
        want FindOne(db *gorm.DB, conds ...any) any
```

Answer (score 1):

The go language usually requires you to be explicit about the types you're using, and generally does not automatically cast variables for you. So this doesn't work because `Model[any]` (aka `Model[interface{}]`) and `Model[Schedule]` are not the same types. (*more details below*)

What you could do instead, is also make `get` a generic func:

```
func get[T any](m Model[T]) Model[T] {
    return m
}
```

and then indicate what the type is when you call the func:

```
func a() {
    m := DbOperations[Schedule]{}
    get[Schedule](m)
}
```

#### Details

`Model[any] != Model[SomeType]` for the same reason why you can't pass a string slice to a func that takes an `any` slice parameter:

A `[]interface{}` slice has a different memory layout than a `[]Schedule` slice. Similarly, a `Model[T]` is laid out in memory differently than a `Model[any]`. Go expects you to do the work of converting them. (summarizing the [official explanation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice) and SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12753805/2487336))